# Apache Spark-Scala implicit conversion with a loop

Tags: apache-spark, implicit-conversion

Good morning,
I m using Scala with Apache Spark, and I have a problem with a simple code line:

```
for ( i<- 0 until imageFileBytes.length)
```

this code give this warning:

```
Implicit conversions found: 0 => intWrapper(0)
```

I use sbt for the dependecies and to compile the code for spark with the command "sbt compile" 
During this compilation sbt return an error:

```
Reference to method intWrapper in class LowPriorityImplicits should not have
survived past type checking, it should have been processed and eliminated during
expansion of an enclosing macro.
[error]for ( i<- 0 until imageFileBytes.length)
```

Someone knows how to resolve this problem?

Comment: could you provide more context? If I try your code on the REPL it works fine.

Comment: I m using spark on linux 64 bit, and i compile the project with the command "sbt clean compile"        my dependencies en simple.sbt are:  
  
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"  
  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.1.0"  
  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"  
  
I m using also opencv for Scala (JavaCV project)  
  
this my file of the project  
https://bitbucket.org/aconese/spark-fib/get/9efc07c89921.zip

Comment: have you tried removing the unnecessary `var i=0` above that for-comprehension?

Comment: yes,
i try to remove var i=0
i tried for (val i <- ...)
and i try to create a range also. val r : Range = 0 to 10
for ( i <- r )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spark. You have conflicting versions Scala in your build file:
While the Scala version is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

There's a dependency to the 2.11 scala compiler:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scalap" % "2.11.3"
```

Changing that last dependency to match the main Scala version will solve the problem:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scalap" % "2.10.4"
```